# Mock inner methods Python2

Tags: python, mocking, python-2.6

I'm new to mock and really strugling with it. Mostly in documentation and most of SO pages it shows how to get the mock `result_value`, but  I want to check if the values I'm getting from methods are correct, not the `result_value`'s. Here's the example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Example:

    def one(self):
        return 1

    def two(self, one):
        print(one + 1) # basically any void method, ex: result = one + 1 and check result value if correct

    def main(self):
        self.two(self.one())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    e = Example()
    e.main()
```

Test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest
import example
from mock import patch

class Example(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_one(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, et.one())

    def test_two(self):
        with patch('example.Example.two'):
            self.assertEqual(2, et.two(et.one())) # ..the part I'm stuck
                                                  # whick ofc throws AssertionError: 2 != <MagicMock name='two()' id='blablabla'>

    def test_main(self):
        # unknown part..

if __name__ == '__main__':
    et = example.Example()
    unittest.main()
```

How to achieve void method check with unittest?

UPDATE:

so the print I figured out with chepner's help:

```
def test_twoi3(self):
        mock_print = MagicMock()
        with patch('sys.stdout', mock_print):
            print(2)
            expected = call.write('2')
            self.assertEqual(mock_print.mock_calls[0], expected)
```

and for `main` I'm not quite sure if it is a good solution...:

```
def test_main(self):
        with patch ('example.Example.main') as m:
            et.main(et.two(1))
        m.assert_called_with(et.two(1))
```

but I want to check not by passing the methods and values, but if `main` calls other two methods. How to achieve this?

Comment: You need to capture standard output, not check its return value. Mocking isn't really appropriate here, because the mock replaces the body, eliminating the side effect. You can't mock the thing you want to test.

Comment: @chepner okay, how to test the ```main``` if the methods has been called and get their values (not return_value's)?

Comment: You can mock *`print`*, and check that it gets called with the expected value(s), rather than actually writing to standard output.

Comment: Or use `contextlib.redirect_stdout` to capture standard output to a `StringIO` object whose contents you can check.

Comment: @chepner with ```print``` it results with ```None``` (code: ```with patch('__builtin__.print', mock_print): self.assertEqual(2, et.two(1))```

Comment: @chepner could you produce the solution code example you think could help me?

Comment: Yes, because `et.two` *still* does not return 2. If you are mocking `print`, you will check that `print` is called with `2` as its argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to test if main methods have been called. Test looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest
import example
from mock import patch, MagicMock, call

class Example(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.et = example.Example()

    def test_one(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, self.et.one())

    def test_two(self):
        mock_print = MagicMock()
        with patch('sys.stdout', mock_print):
            print(2)
            expected = call.write('2')
            self.assertEqual(mock_print.mock_calls[0], expected)

    def test_main(self):
        self.et.two = MagicMock(side_effect=self.et.two)
        self.et.one = MagicMock(side_effect=self.et.one)

        self.et.main()

        self.et.one.assert_called()
        self.et.two.assert_called()

        self.et.one.__str__ = self.et.one
        self.assertEqual(1, int(self.et.one))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Upon mocking methods that are in `main` (all of them) and calling `main` methods `one` and `two` have been successfully called. For `one` you can return value by using `__str__`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mock anything (directly, anyway); you want to capture standard output and verify that it is what you expect.

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from io import StringIO

def test_two(self):
    stdout = StringIO()

    with redirect_stdout(stdout):
        et.two(et.one())

    self.assertEqual(stdout.getvalue(), "2\n")
```

Or, you can mock the `print` and check that it is *called* with the expected arguments.

```
def test_two(self):
    with patch('__builtin__.print') as p:
        et.two(et.one())

    p.assert_called_with(2)
```

Comment: Could second solution work for testing ```main``` by passing ```.._with(self.et.two(self.et.one)``` and patching ```example.Example.main```?

Comment: The second one would simply call `et.main()` instead of `et.two(et.one())` in the body of the `with` statement; the patch itself wouldn't change.

Comment: As an aside, it would be better to override `setUp` to make `et` an attribute of the test case, so that you get a fresh object for each method, rather than relying on a shared global value.

Comment: in my UPDATE I have the main test calling ```et.main()```, but how to check if the ```self.two(self.one)``` is called. The ```assert_called_with()``` (empty) is not the way to check I think